# Cannot casting Object queried by Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm using Hibernate to access and record data to database.

Everything was fine until I used HQL to join mapped table and query some objects from database. As a result, I got a `List<Object[]>` contains data. But when I got the Object array, an exception appeared

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException:  com.aperture.demo.entities.Order cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
>   at com.aperture.demo.controller.MainAppController$OrderTableMouseListener.mouseClicked(MainAppController.java:113)
>       at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:270)
>       at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6536)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
>       at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
>       at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2237)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2295)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4889)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4467)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2281)
>       at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

I've tried any ways I can, like, make the List Iterable, cast the Object[] to Order[] (my object), but the results are the same. I use Debugger of the IDE, but it looked fine, like this

[View post on imgur.com](https://imgur.com/sRleYM5)

(Stack Overflow doesn't let me embeded image here, sorry!)

I don't understand what does the "[L" mean, and why did it keep making my project crash.

My Object

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Order extends MyObject implements Serializable {
    //something
}
```

The method that get the object from DB

```
public List<Object[]> listJoinedTable(int id) {

    Transaction tx = null;
    List<Object[]> result = null;
    try (Session session = sessionFactory.openSession()) {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        //language=HQL
        String hql = "SELECT o FROM Order o INNER JOIN FETCH o.productList WHERE o.orderId = " + id;
        result = session.createQuery(hql).list();
        tx.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (tx != null) tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Code that fires bug

```
if (mouseEvent.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
            final JTable target = (JTable) mouseEvent.getSource();
            final int row = target.getSelectedRow();
            final int id = (int) mainAppFrame.getOrderList()
                    .getModel()
                    .getValueAt(0, 0);
            List<Object[]> recordList = ((AdvancedLoader<Order>) orderLoader).listJoinedTable(id);
            for (int i = 0; i < recordList.size(); i++) {
                Order[] myObjects = (Order[]) recordList.get(i); //Bug here
            }
        }
```

Please help me, thanks a lot!

Comment: 1. Post the full stacktrace 2. Post your code

Comment: Okay wait a minute

Comment: records.get(i) gives you an instance of `Order`. Why would you want to cast this into an `Array of Object`?

Comment: @FlorianCramer totally wrong. `recordList.get(i)` gives array of `Object`

Comment: in `listJoinedTable` method, why don't you return a list of orders? hibernate is good at returning objects of the class you need

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Wow thanks a lot! It works :)) How can I upvote or do smth for you?

Comment: @HaiVuQuang Post your solution as an answer, and accept it. That's what you should do, rather than edit the question and post the answer there.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer. You are totally wrong. The debug output in the attached Image clearly states that the first element in `recordlist` is of type `Order`. Just because you cast a raw `List` to a `List<Object[]>` the list does not automatically contain instances of `Object[]`, hence the ClassCastException. Please read about how Java handles (or better does not handle) generics at runtime.

Comment: even if you are right this time, `Why would you want to cast this into an Array of Object` is wrong. if at all, he wants to cast into an array of orders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to XtremeBaumer, I'd solved the problem. Hibernate is good at returning objects of the class you need (Baumer said), so we needn't to use List. Just use List to get the Object you want. I mapped the object Order with object Product, so when I join two table, i just get only one object is Order. If you join some completely unmapped tables, you may still need List.

Answer (score 0):

"[L" represents that the object is an array of `long`,  you should use collection to receive the result.